# How to add dynamic multiple file attached for custom post type meta box in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to make a custom post type named `books` for my WordPress site. My current code can upload one file from meta box. is there any way to upload multiple file dynamically or on condition based for custom post type from meta box ?

My current code

```
<?php
function add_custom_meta_boxes() {

    // Define the custom attachment for posts
    add_meta_box(
        'wp_custom_attachment',
        'Custom Attachment',
        'wp_custom_attachment',
        'books', //post type name
        'side'
    );

} // end add_custom_meta_boxes
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_boxes');

function wp_custom_attachment() {

    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce');

    $html = '<p class="description">';
    $html .= 'Upload your PDF here.';
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25" />';

    echo $html;

} // end wp_custom_attachment


function save_custom_meta_data($id) {

    /* --- security verification --- */
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_custom_attachment_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if('books' == $_POST['post_type']) {
      if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
        return $id;
      } // end if
    } else {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
            return $id;
        } // end if
    } // end if
    /* - end security verification - */

    // Make sure the file array isn't empty
    if(!empty($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'])) {

        // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just PDF.
        $supported_types = array('application/pdf');

        // Get the file type of the upload
        $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name']));
        $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

        // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.
        if(in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)) {

            // Use the WordPress API to upload the file
            $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name']));

            if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
                wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
            } else {
                add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);
                update_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);     
            } // end if/else

        } else {
            wp_die("The file type that you've uploaded is not a PDF.");
        } // end if/else

    } // end if

} // end save_custom_meta_data
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data');

function update_edit_form() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} // end update_edit_form
add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'update_edit_form');
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading multiple files requires you to work with `$_FILES` in a different way, because of how PHP organize the upload data. See [this documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) for more info.

Another issue in your code is it doesn't generate metadata for the uploaded files, which make them not available in the Media Library.

To avoid these issues, I'd suggest using a [custom fields plugin](https://metabox.io) to handle them for you automatically.

Comment: Indeed using the raw php documentation for multiple input files would make the trick, although I don't see it necessary to use metadata for the uploaded files in case you just need to upload files instead of images. Just following the php documentation and adapting the current code would make the trick. No need to complicate it.